# Problems running Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu (Maverick)

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, apache-http-server

Yesterday I started [this](https://superuser.com/questions/272571/cant-seem-to-run-apache-2-2-on-ubuntu-maverick) post but since StackExchange's login system is so strange, I can't seem to log into my account, even using the same exact email and password combo (just treating me as a whole new user).  Anyways I'm referencing that post in this new question.

The answer that @Patches gave me was very thorough and helpful, however when I ran the **netstat** I saw nothing like @Patches described. I saw no tcp/www record on port 80; in fact, my port 80 isn't being used at all! I've modified my *httpd.conf* several times, changing the `Listen` directive to all sorts of values: 8080, 8081, 38, 984, etc. and I get **the same error (see other post)** every single time!!! Here's what my netstat dump looks like:

```
myUser@myMachine:/etc$ sudo netstat --tcp --udp --listening --program
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address   Foreign Address   State     PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:mysql *:*       LISTEN    1188/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdoma:ipp *:*       LISTEN    1115/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 myMachine:ipp           [::]:*    LISTEN    1115/cupsd      
udp        0      0 *:mdns                  *:*                 888/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 *:bootpc                *:*                 1770/dhclient   
udp        0      0 *:51367                 *:*                 888/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 [::]:mdns               [::]:*              888/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 [::]:53539              [::]:*              888/avahi-daemon: r
```

So as you can see, no lighttpd or anything else listening on 80, 8080, or any of the other ports I mentioned trying.

*Please help!*  About to abandon Linux altogether - on Windows I'd already have PHP and CodeIgniter up and running...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for delay in looking at this for you - been a busy few days!! Thanks for pasting your httpd.conf, the problem is that you have 2 listen directives. The first one tells apache to listen on port 8080 on ALL ips(because you haven't specified), the second one then tries to get it to listen on port 8080 on 127.0.0.1 but of course this is already being used by the previous directive.

Take the first directive out and Apache will listen only on your localhost address - of course if you want it to listen on more ips then you can add these as well.

Enjoy :)

S

Comment: thanks for the encouragement, [here's](http://pastie.org/1811133) my httpd; thanks for any help!

Comment: Could this be a permissions issue? I installed via Synaptic (possibly "as root"). Even though I am using sudo to start apachectl I wanted to throw this out there because I'm still learning Linux permissions.

Comment: @Pam You need to install and run it using `sudo`, that should be fine. As long as you've installed it from the Ubuntu repositories that's the normal procedure.

Comment: @slhck - Thanks for your suggestion, but I have already ruled that out as a culprit. I am starting Apache using `sudo apachectl start` and am getting the error you see in my original post from yesterday which is linked to up above.